# Grouping and counting methods, same answer for two different questions?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

There is a set of $5$ distinct history books, $3$ distinct math books, and $2$ distinct art books.

**a)** In how many ways can these books be arranged on a shelf if all $5$ history books are on the left and both art books are on the right? 
My answer: $5*4*3*2*1*3*2*1*2*1 = 1,440$

**b)** In how many ways can these books be arranged on a shelf if all books of the same discipline are grouped together?

My answer: 

Ways to group history books: $5*4*3*2*1 = 5! = 120$

ways to group math books: $3*2*1 = 3! = 6$

ways to group art books: $2*1 = 2$

So the ways to put the three groups next to each other: $120*6*2 = 1,440$

I got the same answer for both, but I am pretty sure one of them has to be wrong. My guess is that I did A wrong.

Comment: A is right.  B is wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to multiply the second answer by 3!

Do you see why?

There are 3! ways to arrange the three disciplines.  You didn't take that into account and calculated as though one specific discipline must come first, then another, then the third.